# How to add null terminator to a char *table[20][20]?(C)

Tags: arrays, pointers, null, char

I'm working with a

```
char *table[20][20].
```

At some point while manipulating it, I need to assign it a char number as such:

```
*table[x][y] ='1';
```

and then a null terminator after the number .
I tried placing the null terminator like this:

```
*(table[x][y]+1) = '\0';
```

but it still prints out garbage after the 1 value and 0 value.
Here is the code I used to print out the table:

```
for (i = 0; i <= nrLines; i++) {
   for (j = 0; j < m; j++)
    for(t=0;t<strlen(table[i][j]);t++)
        printf_s("%c", *(tabla[i][j]+t));
printf_s("\n");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The method I chose to assign was correct, I had a problem somewhere else in the code where I did:

```
table[x][y++]= something;
*(table[0][y]+1)='\0';
```

which was adding the null terminator to the next column of my table and not the current one because, well,  I got lost in the code :) .